# How to create 2 payments for the same Order in Magento?

Tags: orders, cart, payment, quote, edit-order

Service company has a magento shop.

- User can choose specific defect for specific device and make an order.
- After several days service company can change an order. Service company manager should be able to do changes in backend and charge user with additional payment.
- User should be able to pay an additional payment from his account.

For example:

- User orders `Change display in iPhone 5` for `200 EUR`.
- After 6 days service checks device and says that it should be `Change CPU in iPhone 5` for `300 EUR`.
- User should be notified and been able to login to his account and pay additionally `100 EUR` and fix his iPhone.

Is it possible in Magento to change existing Order and create additional payment?

Comment: No. What you want is against the way I understand the accounting rules. Magento cancels the order and creates a new one with all the new stuff. The problem is, during this process you get a lot of problems with shipping and payment ,because this is not copied :( Therefore I would recommend to either do it this way or just make a second order. Beside of this, I read about a lot of technical problems, charging more for an order in magento...

Comment: Now I am trying to create another order for this purpose. It seems that to work with existing order is too much effort.

Comment: This functionality isn't included with Magento. I think it is probably possible to have a developer program this in, but my gut feeling is that it will be big effort and hacking of core Mage will be involved.